# VBS for opening the Windows 10 task view

Tags: vbscript, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, dwm

I have an Elan touchpad on my notebook. Sadly the driver does not support the new "task view" feature, only executing external programs.

I already found out: it's not possible to send the WIN key via vbs and also this solution suggested

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.WindowSwitcher
```

does not work anymore. Same goes with the rundll32 solution.

I DON'T want to install 3rd party thingies.
So, is there solution to this?

Comment: why not press WIN-KEy + Tab to show the taskview?

Comment: Well, this should just be an addition. To make it more MAC stylish.

Comment: I don't use a Mac so I have no idea what you want to achieve. use the default shortcut combination and it will work for all Win10 PCs that you use

Comment: My keyboard has the Win key on the right side, so I need both hands for the shortcut. Thats why I would love to show the task view via a touchpad gesture.

Answer (score 1):

If you include `()` after `windowswitcher` it worked for me. On 7 it worked fine without, but I suppose 10 is a bit more picky:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.WindowSwitcher()
```